# Shortcut for the "Update selected" feature in the attribute table with QGIS

Tags: qgis, table, windows

I am using QGIS version 3.28 on Windows 11 and I use the attribute table all the time and I was wondering if there was a way to set up a shortcut for the "Update selected" feature since it would save me up some time during the work day.

I've tried looking in the shortcut menu but there was nothing and I've searched online with no results.

Comment: Which tool/button exactly are you talking about? I couldn't find "update selected" in the documentation.

Comment: @Erik I think OP means this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G87PX.png

Comment: @Babel Exactly, I ment that button on the right.